# MYSQL UNION JOIN SUM(amount) output two result instead of one

Tags: mysql, join, sum, union

I have this below:

```
SELECT a.* FROM ( SELECT
      asset_liability_income_expenditure_tbl.a_l_code,
      SUM(mainaccount_a_2017.amount), mainaccount_a_2017.dr_cr_action 
      FROM `mainaccount_a_2017` LEFT JOIN chart_of_account 
      ON (
         chart_of_account.joint_account_numbers =
         mainaccount_a_2017.joint_account_number
       ) 
      LEFT JOIN asset_liability_income_expenditure_tbl 
      ON (
         asset_liability_income_expenditure_tbl.a_l_code =
         chart_of_account.account_type
      ) 
WHERE asset_liability_income_expenditure_tbl.a_l_code = 'FA' 
      AND mainaccount_a_2017.dr_cr_action = 'DR' UNION 
SELECT asset_liability_income_expenditure_tbl.a_l_code,
SUM(mainaccount_b_2017.amount), 
mainaccount_b_2017.dr_cr_action 
FROM `mainaccount_b_2017` 
LEFT JOIN chart_of_account ON (
          chart_of_account.joint_account_numbers = 
          mainaccount_b_2017.joint_account_number
      ) 
LEFT JOIN asset_liability_income_expenditure_tbl ON ( 
           asset_liability_income_expenditure_tbl.a_l_code =
           chart_of_account.account_type
      ) 
WHERE asset_liability_income_expenditure_tbl.a_l_code = 'FA' 
      AND mainaccount_b_2017.dr_cr_action = 'DR' 
) AS a
```

it works fine, but displays either one empty row at the top and the sum below or vis-a-vis. I tried LIMIT 1, but the problem is when the SUM(amount) outputs in row 2, i cannot fetch and if I don't apply any limit, it only fetches result whose SUM(amount) outputs in row 1. I don't know what am missing. Please kindly assist. Thanks.

Comment: please post results and a date dump from the tables

Comment: These are fake outer joins. The query pretends to outer join `chart_of_account` and `asset_liability_income_expenditure_tbl`, but in the WHERE clause you dismiss all a_l_code that are not 'FA', which eventually gets rid of all outer-joined records (with a_l_code null). So the joins are inner joins really. And you join in order to multiply the `mainaccount_a_2017.amount` with the occurence of related 'FA' records? This looks strange.

Comment: Having tables `mainaccount_a_2017` and `mainaccount_b_2017` (well even to have a year in the table name alone) sounds like a bad, bad database design. Hopyfully these are just temp tables, you just set up?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to flip something. Results below:

```
SELECT SUM(a) FROM
(
  SELECT SUM(mainaccount_a_2017.amount) 
  AS a FROM `mainaccount_a_2017`
  LEFT JOIN chart_of_account ON (chart_of_account.joint_account_numbers = mainaccount_a_2017.joint_account_number)

  LEFT JOIN asset_liability_income_expenditure_tbl ON (asset_liability_income_expenditure_tbl.a_l_code = chart_of_account.account_type)

  WHERE asset_liability_income_expenditure_tbl.a_l_code = 'FA' 
  AND mainaccount_a_2017.dr_cr_action = 'DR'

  UNION ALL

  SELECT SUM(mainaccount_b_2017.amount) 
  AS a FROM `mainaccount_b_2017`
  LEFT JOIN chart_of_account ON (chart_of_account.joint_account_numbers = mainaccount_b_2017.joint_account_number)

  LEFT JOIN asset_liability_income_expenditure_tbl ON (asset_liability_income_expenditure_tbl.a_l_code = chart_of_account.account_type)

  WHERE asset_liability_income_expenditure_tbl.a_l_code = 'FA' AND mainaccount_b_2017.dr_cr_action = 'DR'
) a
```